# How to pass parameter from child to parent using function in react with es6 syntax

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am having problem with react while passing argument from child to parent function .

The parent class code is like this

```
setWebSite = (website) => () => {
  console.log(1);
}

getWebsites = () =>{
        return (
            <div>
                <h2 className="text-center">Choose Website</h2>
                <div className="row">
                    {this.state.websites && this.state.websites.map((website)=>{
                        return (
                            <div className='col-sm-4' key={website._id}>
                                <SingleWebsite website={website} key={website._id} setWebSite={this.setWebSite}/>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>

            </div>
        )
};
```

And the child class component is like this

```
const SingleWebsite = ({website,setWebSite})=>{
return (
  <span onClick={()=>{setWebSite(website.name)}}>
      <img  className="img img-responsive" style={{'width':'50%'}} src={'/images/'+ website.name +'.png'} />
  </span>
);
```

}

The setWebsite function is not being called when onsubmit happens . I know something is wrong with my defining function of setWebSite but I don't know what it is . If I remove the parameter then it gets called . Any help will be appriciated

Comment: did you try to use
`<span onClick={()=>{this.setWebSite(this.website.name)}}>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have made setWebSite a function which returns a function which logs 1 to the console. So in order to call that you should call `setWebsite(website.name)()` from your child component. However i do not think that this is what you are interested in?

Instead i think the following will solve your problem

```
setWebSite = (website) => () => {
    console.log(1);
}
```

should probably be

```
setWebSite = (website) => {
  console.log(1);
}
```

Comment: Why not, in the code you have posted i see no reason to use the nested function?
Or did you simplify the code in order to explain the problem?